# Alt+F,S not working in sendKeys C#

Tags: c#, sendkeys, simulate

I want to save and close all kinds of application which is opened. The specific   application is identified from Process command. with this I can kill it.

For saving I tried SendKeys class, First I set the SetForegroundWindow(h), and succeeded with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> by using

```
SendKeys.Send("^s"); //Ctrl+s
```

but, user defined applications are there, and also I have a situation to save a new(not existing file) which has to be saved by **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>**.
So that it saves with default name
How do I achieve this,
I tried,

```
SendKeys.Send("%(fs)");
SendKeys.Send("%f"+"s"); //Alt+F 
SendKeys.Send("%f" + "%s)"); //Alt+F
SendKeys.Send("%fs");
```

Please guide me, If its not possible with SendKeys, what else should I try.

Comment: First send "Alt+F", then wait a second then send "S".

Answer (score 5):

Always use the breakets and you can avoid errors.

```
SendKeys.Send("%{f}"); //Alt+F
SendKeys.Send("{A}"); //A
```

or try

```
SendKeys.Send("%{f}{A}"); //Alt+F And A
```

Answer (score 1):

What APP? SendKeys will send key strokes but under the hood most things use the good old message loop.

```
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, wParam, lParam);
```

c#

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]    
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, String lpWindowName);    
[DllImport("user32.dll")]    
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);    
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
static extern uint RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);

IntPtr hwnd= FindWindow(null, "Window Title");    
SendMessage(hwnd, id, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

To get notepad to save it would be

```
const int WM_COMMAND = 0x111;     
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_COMMAND,777  , NULL);
```

Comment: This method `SendKeys.Send("");` exits because of that. Much easier

Comment: It is, but SendMessage is more robust.

Comment: Its sometimes better to go back to the initial problem. But, I do agree SendKey is easier. Personally I haven't had to use it for about 20 years back in VB days :)

Comment: The problem here is, I don't know what application it is going to deal with. It may be .doc., .dwg., etc., The application to get closed will be a user input. For example, 'WINWORD.exe' for msWord, 'devenv.exe'- for visual studio, etc., this is how the enduser will give input.